# sign out is not working with stream provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

I am wrapping my material app with multi providers, one of the is the stream provider that is listening to this getter.

```
 Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }


 //create user object based on firebase user
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null
        ? User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email)
        : null;
  }
```

here I am basically creating my own User based on firebase user

```
class User with ChangeNotifier {
  final String uid;
  final String email;

  User({this.uid, this.email});
}
```

I have a wrapper that returns either Authentication() or SectionWrapper()

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return user == null ? Authentication() : SectionWrapper();
  }
}
```

In the section wrapper, I have 2 buttons that navigate to 2 different sections of the app.

```
class SectionWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CupertinoButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                child: Text('Go to individual sells'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                      context, IndividualsTabsScreen.routeName);
                }),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            CupertinoButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                child: Text('Go to bookstores'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                      context, BookstoresTabsScreen.routeName);
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The functionality of the sign in works fine with the stream provider. but with the sign out, the UI does not update as i am putting the sign out method in both sections drawer. I tried to put the sign out button in the SectionWrapper() and it did work and signed out with updating the UI (returning Authentication()), but when i put it in the app drawer or any screen inside one of the sections, it signs out, but the UI does not update. I also tried to wrap the drawer with a consumer, it did not work neither.

in the drawer, i tried using this

```
 Consumer<User>(
            builder: (ctx, user, _) => ListTile(
              title: Text('Sign Out'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              onTap: () async {
                print(user.uid.toString()); //prints user id
                await _auth.signOut();
                print(user.uid.toString()); //also prints user id but i am expecting null value.
              },
            ),
          ),
```

when i use the app before refreshing it the uid = null, and after refreshing the app, the app shows authentication screen.
Can you please help me with this i have been struggling with this problem for about 2 weeks.

edit: I tired using stream builder, i ended up with the same problem which requires me to refresh the app to show the authentication widget

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

//    return user == null ? Authentication() : SectionWrapper();
//    return Authentication();

    return StreamBuilder<User>(
        stream: AuthService().user,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return SectionWrapper();
          else
            return Authentication();
        });
  }
}
```

the problem is sure because of the navigator, because i tried to go back to the SectionWrapper() and sign out there, the same problem occurred

Answer (score 0):

Basically, After signing out the users, you are not notifying the listeners that the state of `User` has changed.

Check out this [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifier) here. See how they notify the listeners about new state whenever there is a change in the object with `notifyListeners()` method.

Comment: in the Auth file, I am not using change notifier mixin, I am just listening to the stream above, which detects if the user signed in or not. so what should I do?